# tkinter couldn't connect to display ($DISPLAY problem)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm following a tutorial in order to learn how to use `tkinter`, in the video he just type the code I'm using and he gets a window with the label "Hello World"

I'm using my WSL and I want to display the same window using tkinter but when I run the program I get this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1828, in __init__
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

The code I'm running is this:

```
import Tkinter
#create main window
master = Tkinter.Tk()
myLabel = Tkinter.Label(master, text="Hello World!")
myLabel.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

I saw other discussions like mine and the best option shown is use an x-server on Windows(Xming) but I want to know if there is another option.

I also tried other solutions but they didn't work:
These are some of them:

- Use of the matplotlib library
- `export display 0.0`

I tried this one and it doesn't work, this is the error I get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1828, in __init__
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "0.0"
```

Comment: try running `Tkinter._test()`, as explained [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)... then, consider using `python 3`, as version 2 is deprecated.

Comment: You need to run a X-server.  Or connect to WSL via SSH using `MobaXterm` which has built-in X-server.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I also tried using the python 3 version `tkinter` but nothing changed

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, I saw that in an answer here on StackOverflow but I was wondering if exist another way in WSL

Comment: No, because WSL does not have a graphical desktop.

Comment: @Henry. here is link https://blog.safnet.com/archive/2022/01/21/python-from-wsl/